# Convert Mongo native aggregate query to Spring Data Query

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data, mongotemplate

I am new with `Spring Data` or `MongoRepository`. I am trying to convert below mongo query to `Spring-Data` query in and execute via `Mongo Template`.

```
db.getCollection('NameOf_Col').aggregate(
    { "$match": { "recordDate": "06/05/2021" } },
    { $project: {
    projectName: 1,
        presentCounter: {$cond: ['$present', 1, 0]},
        sickCounter: {$cond: ['$onSickLeave', 1, 0]},
        covidCounter: {$cond: ['$onCovidLeave', 1, 0]}
    }},
    { $group: {
        _id: "$projectName",
        totalPresent: {$sum: '$presentCounter'},
        totalSickLeave: {$sum: '$sickCounter'},
        totalCovidLeave: {$sum: '$covidCounter'}
    }
});
```

Currently I am using `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation` as:

```
public List<ReportDto> getGroupData(String strDate) {
   Aggregation aggTotal = newAggregation(Absence.class,
                match(Criteria.where("recordDate").is(strDate)),
                project("projectName").andExpression(),
      ........

     AggregationResults<AbsenceReportDto> groupResults
                = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggTotal, NameOf_Colllection.class, ReportDto.class);
     List<ReportDto> result = groupResults.getMappedResults();

     return result;
}
```

Comment: what problem are you facing? do you have any code at `.....................`? Do you need help with group aggregation?

Comment: @sidgate: I want to project a native mongo query i.e. 
 $project: {projectName: 1,
        presentCounter: {$cond: ['$present', 1, 0]},
        sickCounter: {$cond: ['$onSickLeave', 1, 0]},
        covidCounter: {$cond: ['$onCovidLeave', 1, 0]}
    }},
    { $group: {
        _id: "$projectName",
        totalPresent: {$sum: '$presentCounter'},
        totalSickLeave: {$sum: '$sickCounter'},
        totalCovidLeave: {$sum: '$covidCounter'}
    } in Spring Data `Aggregation`